# AngularJs checkbox select all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-change

I'm trying to add a checkbox to select/deselect all the item then sum all the item. I have done some code for it. however, both function is separate now and I would like to merge it together to achieve the target.

HTML

```
//Select all checkbox
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkAll()" ng-model="params.checkbox[0]" 
class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty" style="">

//Select a single checkout and do cal balance
<input type="checkbox" name="marked_reconciled" ng- 
model="trx.marked_reconciled" ng-change="calBalance()">
```

This is AngularJs

```
$scope.checkAll = function () { angular.forEach($scope.records, function (v) 
{ $scope.params.checkbox[v.id] = $scope.params.checkbox[0]; }); };

$scope.calBalance = function () {
                if (!$scope.trans) {
                    return;
                }
                var current = 0;
                var statement_mth = new Date($scope.item.reconcile_date).getMonth();
                angular.forEach($scope.trans.trans, function (trx) {
                    var reconcile_mth = new Date(trx.reconcile_on).getMonth();
                    if (trx.marked_reconciled && ((statement_mth == reconcile_mth) || !trx.reconcile_on)) {
                        if (trx.entry == 'debit') {
                            current += parseFloat(trx.amount);
                        } else if (trx.entry == 'credit') {
                            current -= parseFloat(trx.amount);
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
```

I have tried to merge the ng-change as "checkAll();calBalance()" but doesn't work.

Comment: There are only two checkboxes in your html? Are there other checkboxes as well?

Comment: @Nabil Shahid There has other checkboxes in table body and the "check all" checkbox in the first row of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the two checkboxes into one performing both operations i.e. select all and calculate balance on the change on one checkbox. In the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkAllAndCalBalance()" ng-model="params.checkbox[0]" 
class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty" style="">
```

And in the logic create a new function `checkAllAndCalBalance` to do both the tasks. **As the `ng-model` of the other checkbox is not there anymore, you have to set its value manually in your logic so that the computations depending on `trx.marked_reconciled` won't get affected:**

```
 $scope.checkAll = function () { angular.forEach($scope.records, function (v) 
{ $scope.params.checkbox[v.id] = $scope.params.checkbox[0]; }); };

$scope.calBalance = function () {
                if (!$scope.trans) {
                    return;
                }
                var current = 0;
                var statement_mth = new Date($scope.item.reconcile_date).getMonth();
                angular.forEach($scope.trans.trans, function (trx) {
                    var reconcile_mth = new Date(trx.reconcile_on).getMonth();
                    if (trx.marked_reconciled && ((statement_mth == reconcile_mth) || !trx.reconcile_on)) {
                        if (trx.entry == 'debit') {
                            current += parseFloat(trx.amount);
                        } else if (trx.entry == 'credit') {
                            current -= parseFloat(trx.amount);
                        }
                    }
                });
    };

$scope.checkAllAndCalBalance = function(){
    //as not specified in ng-model, setting the value of trx.marked_reconciled manually in logic
    $scope.trx.marked_reconciled=$scope.params.checkbox[0];
    //select all  
    $scope.checkAll();
    //calculate balance
    $scope.calBalance();
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you only consider to have single function to handle both the checkbox, then you can have a single function with if condition to differentiate from two different checkbox control.

```
//Select all checkbox
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkBoxSelection('All')" ng-model="params.checkbox[0]" 
class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty" style="">

//Select a single checkout and do cal balance
<input type="checkbox" name="marked_reconciled" ng- 
model="trx.marked_reconciled" ng-change="checkBoxSelection('')"> 


$scope.checkBoxSelection = function(mode){
    if(mode==='All'){
        angular.forEach($scope.records, function (v) { 
            $scope.params.checkbox[v.id] = $scope.params.checkbox[0]; 
        });
    }else {
       if (!$scope.trans) {
           return;
       }
       var current = 0;
       var statement_mth = new Date($scope.item.reconcile_date).getMonth();
       angular.forEach($scope.trans.trans, function (trx) {
           var reconcile_mth = new Date(trx.reconcile_on).getMonth();
           if (trx.marked_reconciled && ((statement_mth == reconcile_mth) || !trx.reconcile_on)) {
               if (trx.entry == 'debit') {
                   current += parseFloat(trx.amount);
               } else if (trx.entry == 'credit') {
                   current -= parseFloat(trx.amount);
               }
           }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested the function already but the checkbox still can't select all. The key is the ng-model which is params.checkbox[0] and trx.marked_reconciled. If I replace the trx.marked_reconciled using params.checkbox[0], It can select all the checkbox but the item won't calculate.

Comment: Are you looking to merge the template checkbox control into one for those two different behaviour?